# Using mixin() function with lodash and JSONSelect

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

I know that lodash (and underscore) have a [mixin()](http://lodash.com/docs#mixin) function that's supposed to let you extend lodash with your own properties.

For my use-case it works . . . kind of.

I want to add JSONSelect.match to lodash so that I can use it within a chain. It works when you only call `_.match(selector, object)`, but not in a chain.

In other words, I can do:

> _.match('.name', cars);

and

> _.match('.name', _(cars).chain().value());

but not

> _(cars).chain().match('.name').value();

Here's a fiddle -- the first 3 buttons work and the last one doesn't. How can I fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/marclar/sBGR6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage is incorrect.
Normally Underscore/Lo-Dash methods follow this pattern:

```
_.foo(value, arg1, arg2);
```

When chaining it shifts to

```
_(value).chain().foo(arg1, arg2);
```

and supplies `value` to `_.foo(value, ...)` internally.

So in your example `_.match('.name', cars)` should be changed to `_.match(cars, '.name')`.
This would allow for `_(cars).chain().match('.name').value()` to work.

Keep in mind when using Lo-Dash chaining is automatic w/o `.chain()`, though `.chain()` is supported in the `lodash underscore` compat builds.

Comment: Yeay-yYAYYY!!! Got it working, thanks to you. New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marclar/sBGR6/5/

Comment: And yes, I'm using the underscore-compatible build. Thanks, John-David!